Maximum of $\sum_{n=1}^N z^T X(P_n X + I)^{-1}z$ over unit trace, positive semidefinite matrices?
Let $z$ denote a unit vector.
Fix a finite collection of positive semidefinite matrices $\mathcal{P}$.
Define the function and set
$$
f_{\mathcal{P}}(X) = \sum_{P \in \mathcal{P}} z^T X(PX + I)^{-1} z, 
\quad \mbox{and} \quad 
\mathcal{X} = \{X \succeq 0,~\mathrm{trace}(X) = 1\}. 
$$
Above, $X \succeq 0$ means that $X$ is a real, symmetric, and positive semidefinite matrix.
I am interested in the following quantities,
$$
f^\star_{\mathcal{P}} = \sup_{X \in \mathcal{X}} f_{\mathcal{P}}(X) 
\quad \mbox{and} \quad 
X^\star_{\mathcal{P}} = \mathrm{argmax}_{X \in \mathcal{X}} f_{\mathcal{P}}(X).
$$
By continuity and compactness, the supremum is attained and both quantities are well-defined.
In the case $|\mathcal{P}| = 1$, I am able to directly compute this. I obtain
$$
f^\star_{\mathcal{P}} = z^T(I + P)^{-1} z \quad \mbox{and} \quad 
X^\star_{\mathcal{P}} = \frac{(I+P)^{-1} zz^T (I + P)^{-1}}{z^T (I+P)^{-2} z}.
$$
Above, $\mathcal{P} = \{P\}$.
However, my proof does not generalize to $|\mathcal{P}| > 1$. I am wondering if there is a more clever way to obtain this result.

I should add, even a solution in the case $|\mathcal{P}| = 2$ would be helpful.

This is an interesting problem, there are many ways to look at it. It might help if you say more on what you tried so far and why it failed. You may know things others don't know and vice versa.

Well, as I mentioned above, the only case I could make progress on was the case of $|\mathcal{P}| = 1$. In that case, it is clear from the upper bound argument it has no hope of generalizing to cardinality larger than 1. (Simply because the inequality $z^T X (PX + I)^{-1} z \preceq z^T (P + I)^{-1}z $ is not very strong for $X \in \mathcal{X}$, in the sense that it holds for any direction $z$.)

Did you mean $\le$?

How did you come up with $X^\star_{\mathcal{P}}$?

Indeed, I mean $\leq$ (sorry, I had originally written the operator inequality, because as I mentioned, it holds for all $z$). I came up with $X^\star_\mathcal{P}$ in the case $|\mathcal{P}| = 1$ with the intuition that $(P + X^{-1})^{-1}$ should "align" with $z$. I looked at rank-one products $vv^T$, and maximizing over these leads to the result. However, I can see from simulation already that in the case $\mathcal{P}$ the optimum could have rank larger than 1.

One can also write by continuity $X(PX + I)^{-1} = \sqrt{X}(\sqrt{X} P \sqrt{X} + I)^{-1} \sqrt{X}$. So we can instead look at optimizing $z^TL(L^T P L + I)^{-1} L^T z$ identifying $L$ as the Cholesky factor; $X = LL^T$.

How do you mean, by continuity? Please explain.

Well, if $X \succ 0$, we certainly have $X(PX + I)^{-1} = \sqrt{X} (\sqrt{X} P \sqrt{X} + I)^{-1} \sqrt{X}$. However, now replace $X = X + \tau I$ and take the limit $\tau \to 0^+$ to see it holds if $X \succeq 0$ is singular.

Ok thanks for explaining, I will have one final look at it tomorrow, using this rewrite you just gave me.

I can give you necessary and sufficient conditions for a local maximum (without using Lagrange multipliers). They seem to simplify even further if I rewrite the functional as you suggested. Although they are not that complicated, I don't know how to solve them. Let me know if this is worth anything to you, or if you knew this already.

Does this condition look something like equating a trace inner product to a maximal eigenvalue?

No it doesn't look like that at all.

These are purely algebraic equations in terms of the unknown $L$.

It will take me about one hour to type the argument for you. The derivation is quite elegant. Let me know if you want it.

If you have the time, yes it would be great to see it.

We will derive the necessary and sufficient conditions for a local maximum of the functional
$$ g(L) := \sum_{P \in \mathcal{P}} z^T L L^T(P L L^T + I)^{-1} z = z^T L(L^T P L + I)^{-1} L^T z,$$
where $L$ is a real $n\times n$ matrix with $\mathrm{trace}(L L^T) = 1$ (you essentially proved the above equality in the comments, the equations simplify somewhat further by using this).
The main trick is to view $L$ as a vector in $\mathbb R ^{n^2}$ lying on the $(n^2-1)$-dimensional unit sphere. The special orthogonal group $SO(n^2)$ acts transitively on this sphere, so if we fix some vector $v \in \mathbb R ^{n^2}$ on the unit sphere then we can instead of $g$ maximize the functional on $SO(n^2)$ given by
$$ h(R):=\sum_{P \in \mathcal{P}} z^T [Rv]([Rv]^T P [Rv] + I)^{-1} [Rv]^T z,$$
where $R \in SO(n^2)$ and where the square brackets turn a column vector of length $n^2$ in a $n\times n$ matrix (say row by row starting at the upper left corner).
Since the Lie algebra of $SO(n^2)$ is the set of $n^2\times n^2$ skew-symmetric matrices (see for example 'Introduction to smooth manifolds' by John Lee), the necessary and sufficient conditions for a local maximum $R$ become
$$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}h(e^{tA}R)=0,$$
$$\left.\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\right|_{t=0}h(e^{tA}R)\le 0,$$
for any $n^2\times n^2$ skew-symmetric matrix $A$. We will work out the first order conditions and leave working out the second order conditions to the interested reader.
Let $\overline{E}_{ab}$ be a $n^2\times n^2$ elementary matrix (so zeros everywhere except at position $ab$ where it is $1$). Because the first order conditions are linear in $A$ we only need to consider $$A_{pqrs}:=\overline{E}_{((p-1)n+q)((r-1)n+s)}-\overline{E}_{((r-1)n+s)((p-1)n+q)}$$ in them, for $1\le p,q,r,s \le n$.
We can compute that $$[A_{pqrs}Rv]= E_{pr}[Rv]E_{sq}-E_{rp}[Rv]E_{qs}$$ (where $E_{ij}$ is a $n\times n$ elementary matrix).
We get
\begin{align*}
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}h(e^{tA_{pqrs}}R)=\sum_{P \in \mathcal{P}} & z^T [A_{pqrs}Rv]([Rv]^T P [Rv] + I)^{-1} [Rv]^T z + z^T[Rv]([Rv]^T P [Rv] + I)^{-1} [A_{pqrs}Rv]^T z 
\\& - z^T[Rv]([Rv]^T P [Rv] + I)^{-1} ([A_{pqrs}Rv]^T P [Rv]+[Rv]^T P [A_{pqrs}Rv])([Rv]^T P [Rv] + I)^{-1} [Rv]^T z.
\end{align*}
Finally writing $L=[Rv]$ and using the above expression for $[A_{pqrs}Rv]$ we can simplify the above to
\begin{align*}
0=\sum_{P \in \mathcal{P}} z^T (I- L(L^T P L + I)^{-1} L^T P) (E_{pr}L E_{sq}-E_{rp} L E_{qs})(L^T P L + I)^{-1}L^T z.
\end{align*}
